# Divide screen on five equal circles

Tags: android, vector, xamarin, geometry

How to divide screen on five equal circles. 
I am using xml file as backgorung for circles

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
 <shape android:shape="oval">
 <solid android:color="#59d5fe"/>
 </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

and this is the code

```
LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/img6"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:id="@+id/img1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:id="@+id/img2"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:id="@+id/img3"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     android:id="@+id/img4"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:id="@+id/img5"
     android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Particularly i want the size of the height to be the same as size of the width, but it is giving blank screen until the size is predefined in dp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `ImageView` width is depends on screen width. And you did not set the size of the sharp.

I think you need a square `ImageView` that should be defined by yourself with following code:

```
namespace SharpText_Demo
{
    [Register("sharpText_Demo.SquareImageView")]
    public class SquareImageView : ImageView
    {
        public SquareImageView(Context context):base(context)
        {

        }

        public SquareImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs):base(context,attrs,0)
        {

        }

        public SquareImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle):base(context,attrs,defStyle)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            SetMeasuredDimension(GetDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec), GetDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec));
            int childWidthSize = MeasuredWidth;
            //SET  height = width
            heightMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

set the `ImageView` height always equals its' width.

Then change your axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/img6"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <SharpText_Demo.SquareImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
            android:id="@+id/img1" />
        <SharpText_Demo.SquareImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
            android:id="@+id/img2" />
        <SharpText_Demo.SquareImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
            android:id="@+id/img3" />
        <SharpText_Demo.SquareImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:background="@drawable/vectorshape"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <SharpText_Demo.SquareImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:background="@drawable/vectorshape" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Forget scaleType it is used for `android:src = ....`

you will get the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: And how to connect it with activity because I got this error Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class SharpText_Demo.SquareImageView on SetContentView

Comment: Beautiful explanation the error was probably because in register the SharpText_Demo.SquareImageView was with lower s. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making your `vectorshape` as an image like circle.png (width = height). And using attribute of `ImageView`  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to `wrap_content` your `ImageView`. Your ImageView like this:

```
<ImageView
            style="@style/imv_circle_group"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/circle" />
```